# Angular call a function after 2 http calls are finished

Tags: angular, function, http

I am using angular4 what I want to achieve is that a function is called after 2 or 3 calls are finished.

example:

```
  this.Get.firstGet().subscribe( data=> {

               this.test();
          });

  this.Get.secondGet().subscribe( data=> {

               this.test();
          });

  test(){
    //do something when firstGet and secondGet are both finished

   }
```

thx for the help!

Comment: `forkJoin(this.Get.firstGet(), this.Get.secondGet()).subscribe(([get1, get2]) => this.test())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are separately calling `this.test();` in each `subscribe()` so by your code you are calling it twice.

I believe what you want is [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), this will only execute the success, error blocks when all the Observables are resolved

```
forkJoin(this.Get.firstGet(), this.Get.secondGet()).subscribe(([firstGet, secondGet]) => {
    this.test();
})
```

Comment: but I need the responsevalues are those available?

Comment: @user3356007 yes, `firstGet` and `secondGet` are the response of the first and second get requests, you can access them in subscribe

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combineLatest` from `RxJS` to wait all inner observables to fire at least once

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
...


combineLatest(
   this.Get.firstGet(),
   this.Get.secondGet()
)
.subscribe(([responseOfFirst, responseOfSecond]) => {
     this.test();
})
```

Or you can use `forkJoin` as well: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html